# How to center the text in the the header JSF tag TabView(PrimeFaces)?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Questions have been asked in the topic
The documentation is little information, and CSS I am not strong.

I tried to do:

```
.ui-tabs-nav{
text-align: center;
}
```

How to?

Comment: htmldog.com has really nice HTML, CSS and JS tutorials for beginners.

Comment: And a browser developer tool is a powerfull aid. Make it your friend.